# Pause from reading excel and resume by button click

Tags: java, excel, swing

I'm making a program for attendance monitoring. A part of the program will read from an excel file. That excel file contains many sheets and each sheet contains the schedule of a professor.

This is how that part should run. It will iterate through the sheets of the excel file. Then it will check first if the professor that owns the schedule is already in the database. If yes, the schedule will be added to the database. If not, a swing jframe will show to add that professor in the database.

What I want to know is, when the jframe shows up, how can I pause the reading of the excel file and resume it after clicking the OK button in the jframe? I tried using wait() but the jframe freezes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use listeners & handlers for this ... You cannot use wait as it pauses the  parent thread that will make your application to not respond.

Comment: What are you using to read the excel file?

Comment: How you show new frame?

Comment: @Vlad im using apache POI

Comment: @talex I created the jframe using drag & drop. ex. class is AddProf then I called by frame by AddProf a = new AddProf(); a.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a modal dialog

`public void foo () {
  JDialog jd = new JDialog(null);
  jd.setModal(true);
  ...
  jd.pack();
  jd.show();
  System.out.println("Shows after the dialog is closed");
}`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the excel file is probably happening in a separate thread. Hence you can control and interrupt the thread's flow by using a lock. E.g.

```
new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    for (Sheet sheet: sheets) {
      String professorName = readProfessorNameFromSheet(sheet);
      Optional<Professor> professor = professorService.getProfessorByName(
      if (!professor.exists()) {
        final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition condition = lock.newCondition()

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            NewProfessorDailog dialog = new NewProfessorDialog(); // this can implement JDialog and with modality hardcoded to true 
            dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
              public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                condition.signal();
              }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
          }
        });

        lock.condition.await();
      }
    }
  }

}
```

(The code is not complete, it's just illustrating the approach).